# How to inject Android MockContentResolver into service

Tags: android, testing, android-service, integration-testing, android-contentprovider

I have an Android service that I would like to test in an instrumentation test. The service requires access to a content provider and uses a content resolver for that purpose.

In instrumentation tests I need to use a mock content resolver, which I can acquire from a ProviderTestCase2. The problem now is it is impossible to inject dependencies into a service upon creation and thus it is impossible to inject the content resolver to exchange it for the mock content resolver as part of a test case.

Does anyone have a satisfying solution for this problem?

Comment: Show some code as a [mcve] of what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. A Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example would be a great thing, but probably take me hours to implement. Since I believe, that unfortunately there is no solution to that problem I would rather avoid that. I have just hoped for the small chance that I am wrong and that there is an obvious solution I have overlooked. Luckily I was able to work around the problem for the moment. The workaround is nothing I feel well with, but I guess have to work with until Google changes its APIs. -.-